DC-DC Boost Converter: Can't see switching waveform/ does not boost
I've designed a boost converter to drive a LCD backlight. I'm at the stage of testing the boost converter now. I've used AP3031. I've set the circuit so that the current drawn will be 160mA. This was done by seting the R2 Value as per the datasheet.

I've enabled the control pin to high(3.3V) via ESP32. I expected to get 12.8V across the output with a resistive load of 80 ohms since V= IR = 0.16 X 80 but I get 8.66V. I also cant see the switching waveform on the scope. Am I loading the boost converter incorrectly?
So far I've

Crossed check diode is place the right way.
Cross checked inductor is placed the right way
Cross checked if any pin is shorted to GND on AP3031

Am I missing some fundamental concept? Any guidance would be much appreciated. Could I be driving the CTRL pin incorrectly? Should I be seeing a switching waveform if no load is connected?

Can you show the full schematic, not cut off on the left side. The load details can matter.

Add details about your 9V vin- what is it, current capability?

You've mentioned that set R2 based on LED current of 160mA. Is that what you're actually seeing at $I_{LED}$?

Any chance that you use breadboarding?

This boost circuit even when disabled would allow V_out to rise to V_in - (R_eff of L1)* I - (V_f of D1), which is probably what you observed.  Something is keeping boost IC from operating other than CTRL pin.   Measure voltage on every pin of IC1 relative to its pin 2 gnd, and see what is out of spec (or bad IC ?).

And double check pin 1 location (vs PCB pad) of IC1.   Could it be installed rotated or bad footprint if this is first board sample bring up?

Hi everyone, sorry for the delayed response. I resolved the issue by replacing IC1, and now it works perfectly! Thank you all for your help.

Replaced IC1 and circuit worked as per.
